# Regex remove spaces on Forum

Tags: regex, xenforo

I have some damaged URLs on my forum, something like:

```
 [url = https: //example.com/? post = qwerty]
```

and

```
[/ url]
```

I have to remove spaces. I know, how to find those string using regex replacement extension:

```
/\[url = .*?\]
```

But I don't have an idea, how to replace them with data without spaces. Could someone help me with that? :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a string pick out the substring from where the url begins.
So it should look like this:

```
String substring = https: //example.com/? post = qwerty
```

Then for this substring replace the spaces with "". The regex to find space is: `\s`. Now just replace these with "" i.e. empty string.

Comment: I think they want to removes spaces **within** url.

Comment: [Minor] Edited.